# Running Integration Tests on Remote Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been trying to find a way to run integration tests on a remote server during an Azure pipeline process.  In my situation we have the pipeline running in Azure and deploying to a local server.  I am wondering if there is a way to also deploy integration tests to the same server and run them and report back to Azure in the same process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [self-host agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) to run your pipeline. Since Azure agents cannot communicate with your localDB, you can set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine. Your localDB is accesible to the self-hosted agent.

In order to run Integration Tests in your release pipeline. You can include your Test projects or test assembly dll files in the artifacts published in your build pipeline. So that your Integration test projects are accessible to the test tasks in your release pipeline.

To Include your test files in the artifacts. You can add a second `publish build artifacts` task in your Build Pipeline. Specify `Path to publish` to the location of your test files.

[image]

Run tests in release pipeline by adding the VsTest task or other test tasks in your release pipeline. The release pipeline will download your artifacts to folder `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.

[image]

Visual Studio Test task and Dot NetCore CLI task automatically publish test results to the pipeline, while tasks such as Ant, Maven, Gulp, Grunt, .NET Core and Xcode provide publishing results as an option within the task. Besides you can use [Publish Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml) task.

Here are some articles you can refer to:

- [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [Running UAT and Integration Tests During a VSTS Build](https://dzone.com/articles/running-uat-and-integration-tests-during-a-vsts-bu)
- [Run automated tests from test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 1):

Good question. This comes up if your integration infrastructure is behind a cooperate firewall, for example.

One solution is to use a *self hosted agent* on that very integration infrastructure.

Another straight forward approach is to scp your integration tests to your integration infrastructure, then ssh run them, and scp the test results back. There are Pipeline Tasks for both scp and ssh.

Note that the communication in these alternatives are reversed, i.e. `Hosted Agend calls Pipeline` and `Pipeline calls Infrastructure`. Your corporate security may prefer one over the other.